# cant route traffic to different services using istio ingress gateway

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, kubernetes-ingress, istio

i am new to istio. i have a app deployed on k8s cluster. i want to expose a service to internet using istio ingress gateway. my service runs on port 80. so i created a gateway and virtual service yaml file. when i set prefix as "/" it works fine. but if i set prefix as "/xyz". it doesnt work. help.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: vote
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - my-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /xyz
    route:
    - destination:
        host: vote  # Replace with the actual service name
        port:
          number: 80


and this is the gateway code

apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: my-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess the `vote` service you're routing the traffic to doesn't have a handle for the `/xyz` path. With your current configuration, if you send a request to `http://[yourgateway]/xyz` the traffic is routed to `http://vote/xyz`. If that's not desired, you'll have to rewrite the path after you've matched it.

For example:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: vote
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - my-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /xyz
    rewrite:
      uri: /
    route:
    - destination:
        host: vote  # Replace with the actual service name
        port:
          number: 80
```

The above configuration will still capture the `http://[yourgateway]/xyz` but it will re-write the captured portion (`/xyz`) to `/`, so the request will be sent to `vote/` (instead of `vote/xyz`).

Comment: thanks for the answer. it kinda worked as now if i use /xyz in my ingress DNS, it takes me to vote/ but when app launches, there is only plane html there. now colors or animations are there. again thanks for the answer.